# Breeze entity observables - how to relaibly access custom knockout functions?

Tags: breeze

I have defined some custom knockout observable functions as documented on the knockout site here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html. Breeze seems to be burying the custom functions deeper inside the object hierarchy. For instance ko.observable.fn.myCustomFunction ends up appearing at entity.someProperty.**ko_proto**.__ko_proto__.fn.myCustomFunction instead of at entity.someProperty.myCustomFunction as expected.

How can I reliably access my custom knockout functions on breeze entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem yourself on a spot basis, by attaching a custom function to `entity.someProperty` that delegates to `entity.someProperty.ko_proto.__ko_proto__.fn...`.

I bet you have to attach the function for each instance of the entity. I think the best place to do this is in [a custom EntityType initializer](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities).

The Knockout documentation recommends that you use custom KO functions ***sparingly***. It says so several times. So the proposed workaround should be only a minor inconvenience.